# Why is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{2},i)$ Galois over $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{2})$?

Tags: galois-theory, splitting-field

**Question:**

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{2},i)$ and $F=\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{2})$. Show that $K$ is Galois over $F$ and determine the Galois group $Gal(K/F)$.

**Answer:**

By assuming the first part of the question, I managed to show that $Gal(K/F)\cong Q_8$. However, I couldn't do the first part. I know that it suffices to find an irreduicble polynomials in $F[x]$ that splits in $K[x]$. Any help/hint would be appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3590590/k-mathbbq-sqrt82-i-and-let-f-mathbbq-sqrt-2-find-the-galois) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34417/prove-that-operatornamegal-mathbbq-sqrt82-i-mathbbq-sqrt-2?noredirect=1&lq=1) question.

Comment: You can use the criterion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2765547/are-intermediate-field-extensions-of-a-galois-extension-galois). Of course $K/\Bbb Q$ is Galois, since it is the splitting field of $x^8-2$.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I forgot that tower of extension argument. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{2}, i) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[8]{2}, \frac{1 + i}{\sqrt{2}})$ is the splitting field of $x^8 - 2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.